# HTMLEditorExtender of ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit set up issues

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I  am getting the **"The Sanitizer is not configured in the web.config file. Either install the AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer NuGet package or set the EnableSanitization property to False (insecure)."** error message that a lot of people are getting.

A lot of answers I am finding say to download files, but because the AJAXControlToolKit project has been moved to devexpress, most links are outdated.

Tried to follow the answers provided to [this question](https://forums.asp.net/t/1824233.aspx?Sanitizer%20provider%20is%20not%20configured%20in%20the%20web%20config%20file%20If%20you%20are%20using%20the%20HtmlEditorExtender%20with%20a%20public%20website%20then%20please%20configure%20a%20Sanitizer%20provider%20Otherwise%20set%20the%20Enable%20Sanitization%20property%20to%20false%20), but the links provided to download the necessary dlls are outdated.

So I followed this [page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer/17.1.1) to install the packages by typing

```
Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer -Version 17.1.1.
```

So it dumps two packages: HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.9 and AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.17.1.1.0.

Before that, I physically downloaded the dlls from [here](https://github.com/subgurim/subgurim-maps-demos/tree/master/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.7.0429/lib/45/SanitizerProviders).

After making references to the DLLs, I tried to follow instructions on [this](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx) page to fix the web.config file. But two issues

- AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection cannot be resolved.
- sanitizer is not a valid child element of system.web

The github [page](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/HtmlEditor) on the extender says nothing about modifying the web.config file.

I probably chased around other sites on this issue, but I can't list them all, and it's 2:50 AM and I am at my wit's end.

I know that the AjaxControlToolkit project has been moved to devexpress, but documentation seems to be very hard to find.

EDIT:  I do have AjaxControlToolkit installed and have 3-4 controls from it  working on my web site.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure what is gone wrong in this case, but AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer should work out-of-the-box.

You need is to install Nuget packages [AjaxControlToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/) and [AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer) **of the same version**.
You can do that even if you already installed AJAX Control Toolkit via the installer.

Then, check your Web.config. This line should be presented there:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" />
```

You can look at the Sample Site source code to check how [complete Web.config](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/Web.config) file should look like.

Comment: The old AjaxToolKit site had a fully functional sample project that worked out of the box.  Is there something similar to that?

Comment: Yes, you can download the whole repo https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit and open the project `AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite` there.